# How to properly write a solutions of quadratic equation on one line?

Tags: quadratics

Using this formula

$$x_{1,2}={-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a} = \space \cdots$$

what should be the correct format of the solution if I want to put both roots (x) on one line?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd write $\; x_1, x_2=\dots$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for example:

$$x^2+x-1=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{\pm\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\tag1$$

Or:

$$x^2+x-1=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=-\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\space\vee\space x=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\tag2$$

Comment: In my second equation, I wrote that $x$ can be the one OR the other and that is Mathematically right.